# PuTTY terminal freezes/lags with Vagrant Virtual Box

Tags: performance, virtualbox, vagrant, putty, lag

I'm using Vagrant on Virtual Box. The install scripts automatically set up PuTTY for ssh session with the environment. The thing is, it often is slow and lags. The session will freeze while I type and I have to wait about a minute for the text to appear. I was wondering if anyone else had this issue and what they did to resolve it. Thanks !

Comment: Try a vagrant up with ui boot [enabled](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html) and as soon as possible login as vagrant/vagrant and do a "top". Windows ? Check your antivirus settings and prevent the analyze of the box files ?

Comment: I have this issue OP mentioned, was fine for 3-4 weeks then all of a sudden has slowed down, would also like to find out why.

Comment: @PrivateSniper I am using a program called "mremote" now and am not having this issue anymore. Its weird because mremote is still using putty for its ssh sessions. Anyway, try mremote to ssh into vagrant that might fix this (it did for me)